# Question about complexity of two topics in programming language theory

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming

I am a student who is currently finishing second year of university mathematics. This summer I have to choose a topic for my diploma. Because I am particularly interested in computer science I am seriously considering choosing a topic about programming language theory. But I have one problem - I will be taking a course in programming language theory next semester, so I don't really have any feeling how difficult are different topics in programming language theory.

I have two topics in programming language theory to choose from. These are their short descriptions which were given to me:

1. **Multi-core execution of asynchronous algebraic effects**

If we want the user interface to stay responsive while it waits for a result of some calculation, we have to write programmes asynchrnously which is not always simple. One of the structured approaches to asynchronous programming are asynchronous algebraic effects. They support asynchronousity in theory, but [prototype implementation](https://matija.pretnar.info/aeff/) only simulates such execution. Programming language OCaml, in which the implementation is written, has begun supporting multi-core execution, which allows a sensbile asynchronous implementation and a test of ideas in practice. Diploma should include an elaboration of asynchronous execution and of multi-core version of OCamla and an expansion of the prototype implementation.

Main literature: D. Ahman in M. Pretnar, Asynchronous effects, Proc. ACM Program. Lang. 5(POPL) (2021) 1–28, [doi: 10.1145/3434305](https://doi.org/10.1145/3434305)

2. **System of modules**

All serious programming languages support some technique to divide larger programmes into smaller units. Programming language OCaml has one of the most advanced of those techniques. It allows us to divide our code into modules which can reference one another, hide parts of implementation, fullfil some common signature, they are parametrized with other modules and so on. Diploma should include a presentation about the theory of such system of modules and an implementation of that system in a prototype programming language called [Millet](https://github.com/matijapretnar/millet/).

Main literature: X. Leroy, A modular module system. J. Funct. Program. 10(3): 269-303 (2000), [doi: 10.1017/S0956796800003683](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0956796800003683), [PDF](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/papers/xleroy-modular_modules-jfp.pdf)

My questions are following. If we assume that I have basic knowledge of programming language theory:

a) **Which of these two topics would be more difficult to make a diploma about them?**

b) **Which of these two topics would take more time to make a diploma about them?**

c) **Are any of these two topics so difficult that I couldn't make a diploma about them if I have only had one semester of programming language theory?**

Thank you for helping!

Comment: This question is opinion-based and off-topic on this site. a, b) the difficulty and time are in fact... up to you. c) the topics are unrelated to language theory. No more comments.

Comment: @YvesDaoust a) and b) are a comparison of difficulty of two topics - which is only in some part up to me and in some part up to the true difficulty of the topics. I suppose if I asked you to compare the difficulty of proof of little Fermat theorem and last Fermat theorem, you wouldn't say it's up to me.
c) Could you please elaborate further? In the programming language theory course at our university, we learn about algebraic effects. Both of these topics require one to add a functionality to some programming language. I don't understand why the topics are unrelated to language theory.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. We prefer questions that have objectively correct answers that will be useful both to the asker and others who have the same question in the future. What is or is not a suitable (or difficult) topic for study, projects or research is very much a matter of opinion and depends crucially on the interests and skills of the person who will be doing the work and the support that will be available to them. This is a question that you should be asking your professors / your advisor, but in any case is not suitable here.

Comment: It sounds like you're from my department. Why not knock on the door of one of the four PL experts in the department (D. Ahman, M. Pretnar, A. Simpson and myself), and talk to us directly?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thank you for your comment and advice, I will do that.